# A proof of the Continuity of the inverse matrix function

Tags: matrices, continuity, inverse-function

I would like to see a proof to this fact.

> If  $A$ is an invertible matrix and $B \in \mathcal{L}(\mathbb{R}^n,\mathbb{R}^n)$, that is an bounded linear opertor in $\mathbb{R}^n$. Then, if there holds
>   $$
> \|B-A\| \|A^{-1}\| <1,
> $$
>   we have that B is invertible.

Moreover, if possible, how to use it to prove that the aplication $A \rightarrow A^{-1}$ is continuous?

Answer (score 2):

Since
$$\|I - BA^{-1}\| = \|(A - B)A^{-1}\| \le
\|B-A\|\,\|A^{-1}\| < 1,$$
the Neumann series 
\begin{align*}
 \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} (I-BA^{-1})^k
\end{align*}
converges and therefore (compare https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neumann_series)
\begin{align*}
 (I - (I-BA^{-1}))^{-1} = (BA^{-1})^{-1} 
\end{align*}
exists. Therefore $B$ is invertible.

Comment: That very last equality is wrong.

Comment: Thank you. I think now its correct.

Comment: I guess that the first $<$ in the top formula should be $\leq$.

Comment: Ok. I'm reading. Thank you.

Comment: Ok $B^{-1} = A (BA)^{-1}$.

Comment: In fact, you have proved that $B$ has right inverse. Does this imply that $B$ has an inverse? That is, the right inverse is a left inverse?

Comment: The argument should be $BA^{-1}$ is invertible. Since $A$ is invertible, also $BA^{-1}A = B$ is invertible.

Comment: @user29999 It is a basic fact in linear algebra that a left inverse of a square matrix is also a right inverse, and vice versa.

Comment: I know. However I'm wondering about the existence. If  there is a right inverse, is there a left inverse?

Comment: ...Yes, they are the same, again under the assumption that the matrix is square.

Comment: I puted it as a ask here http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1866972/right-inverse-matriz

Answer (score 2):

To prove the continuity, consider, if $A,B$ are two invertible $n \times n$ matrices then $$\|A^{-1} - B^{-1}\| \le\| A^{-1}B - I\| \|B^{-1}\| \le \|A^{-1}\| \| B-A \| \|B^{-1}\|.$$ This shows that if $\| B- A\|$ is small, then so is $\|A^{-1} - B^{-1}\|.$

Comment: you can also use the formula $A^{-1} = \frac{1}{\text{det}(A)}A^T$, using the continuity of det (polynomials is his coefficients) and the adjoint operation.

Comment: I think it should be $A^{-1} = \frac 1 {\det A} \text{adj}(A)$ where $\text{adj}$ is the adjugate matrix. But yes, your approach is probably simpler. I was trying to reason in a way which is more in the spirit of this particular problem.

Comment: Oops, you're right of course. Indeed my way is simpler, just wanted to mention it, but your way is more natural and probably more insightful

Comment: But if you take $B$ so that $\|A-B\|$ is ismall, however $\|B^{-1}\|$ is large?

Comment: More specifically, $A$ is fixed, however $B$ isn't.

Comment: This doesn't address what happens when $||B^{-1}||$ is large