# Right inverse matrix

Tags: matrices, inverse

I know that if $A, B$ and $C$ are square matrices such that
$$
AC=I \quad \mbox{and} \quad BA=I,
$$

then
\begin{eqnarray*}
AC=I & \Rightarrow & BAC=B\\
& \Rightarrow &IC=B\\
& \Rightarrow &C=B.\\
\end{eqnarray*}

My question is about existence:

> Suppose that a matrix $A$ has a right inverse; that is, there is $C$ so that $AC=I$. Does it suffice to show that $A$ is invertible? That is, is it also true that 
>   $$
> CA=I?
> $$

Comment: Is $A$ supposed to be square? What about $B$ and $C$?

Comment: Yes. It is. Is this necessary?

Comment: Sure I can see now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For example, the non-square matrix $$\pmatrix{1 & 0 & 0\cr 0 & 1 & 0\cr}$$ has right inverse
$$\pmatrix{1 & 0\cr 0 & 1\cr 0 & 0\cr}$$
but no inverse.  On the other hand, for a square matrix the following are equivalent:

- $A$ has a right inverse.
- $A$ has rank $n$, where $A$ is $n \times n$.
- $A$ is invertible.

Comment: Ok but I modfied the question.

Comment: ... and the second part of my answer is for the modified question.